# Is it possible to develop Android Native apps on cyanogenmod?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod

considering new high-end smartphone, so choices are hard.
Been looking at OnePlus One but it says it's running it's own OS cyanogen which is based off 4.4 .

Question: If I get that phone, can I still develop apps the normal way? or is there any problems that arise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never **precisely** know what kind of stuff the vendor did.

But... considering that OnePlus One is just an Oppo child brand (used to fool the buyers :) ), it could be assumed that they have some experience in the field and haven't done anything utterly stupid to the native layer that would make it non-usable.

I believe it should be OK, as it is still mostly android, sometime even more orthodox than other vendors.